# How to get two sting values (terms) in a variable with a function by current date and one month ahead?

Tags: oracle

I am currently trying to create a function, where I can get the current term and one future term. I thought of using the `add_months` function and 1 month, so I can get the current semester and one future semester. I still get only one value, when I am looking for two values. I get 202310 which is the current term and not 202310 and 202360 (this is summer).

```
BEGIN
    SELECT STVTERM_CODE
    INTO v_current_term
    FROM STVTERM
    WHERE SUBSTR(STVTERM_CODE,6)= '0'
    AND **add_months(to_date(SYSDATE),1)** <= STVTERM_END_DATE
    ORDER BY STVTERM_START_DATE;

    RETURN v_current_term;

  EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          v_current_term := 'ERROR';
     RETURN v_current_term;

  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
     RETURN v_current_term;

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   v_current_term := 'ERROR';
    RETURN v_current_term;

END f_get_current_term_0;
```

I assumed by adding that `add_months` in the `WHERE` clause, I would have gotten two values. What I am not understanding?

Comment: **a)** TO_DATE on SYSDATE is wrong; SYSDATE is function that returns DATE datatype. **b)** what is V_CURRENT_TERM's datatype? You said you expect 2 values but - is V_CURRENT_TERM capable of accepting two values? **c)** We don't have your tables so - when you say "you get this and that", we can only try to imagine it. Please, post sample data that illustrate the problem.

Comment: `add_months` takes a date and adds a number of months to it and returns a single date. I have no idea why you think it would return multiple values (it does not).